# How do I run functions inside my main function in python?

Tags: python, function, class, methods, pygame

Please help with my code for a programming assignment. I'm trying to run the RollDice() function, CheckForLaddders() function & CheckForSnakes() function inside my main() function which will run the main game. I have already defined all the global variables like currentPosition1, currentPosition2, ladderList, snakesList & nameList etc.

When i run my code it's saying RollDice() is not defined - which is the initial function I call inside my main. So basically, how would I call those functions within the context of my code? I thought putting all 4 of the above functions in a class (gameOn) would mean they could access each other, essentially becoming methods. But i guess I'm just not executing this correctly.

I know my logic is right, but I'm just a newbie to python/coding.. please help!

class gameOn:

```
 def RollDice():
    if nameList.index(player) == 0:
        diceRollValue = randrange(1,7,1)
        currentPosition1 += diceRollValue
        print (player, " dice is: ", diceRollValue, ", New position is: ", currentPosition1)
        if nameList.index(player) == 1:
            diceRollValue = randrange(1,7,1)
            currentPosition2 += diceRollValue
            print (player, " dice is: ", diceRollValue, ", New position is: ", currentPosition2)

 def CheckForLadder():
    if nameList.index(player) == 0:
        if currentPosition1 in ladderList:
            currentPosition1 += 15
            print ("Great ", player, " ! It's a ladder, Climb up by 15 cells. Your new position is: ", currentPosition1)
    if nameList.index(player)== 1:
        if currentPosition2 in LadderList:
            currentPosition2 += 15
            print ("Great ", player, " ! It's a ladder, Climb up by 15 cells. Your new position is: ", currentPosition2)


 def CheckForSnake():
    if nameList.index(player)== 0:
        if currentPosition1 in snakesList:
            currentPosition1 = currentPosition1 - 10
            print ("Oops!  ", player, " ! You've been bitten, go down 10 cells. Your new position is: ", currentPosition1)
    if nameList.index(player)== 1:
        if currentPosition2 in snakesList:
            currentPosition2 = currentPosition2 - 10
            print ("Oops!  ", player, " ! You've been bitten, go down 10 cells. Your new position is: ", currentPosition2)


 def main():
      while (currentPosition1 == 0 and currentPosition2 == 0):
           for player in nameList:
                RollDice()# How do I run this function which I've created above?
           print("\n")
      while (currentPosition1 <= 105 or currentPosition2 <= 105):
           for player in nameList:
                RollDice()# How do I run this function which I've created above?
                CheckForLadder()# How do I run this function which I've created above?
                CheckForSnake()# How do I run this function which I've created above?
           print("\n")

           if currentPosition1 >= 100:
                print ("\n")
                print  ("Huuuuray! Winner is ", player1)
                print ("Press any key to exit")
                break

           if currentPosition2 >= 100:
                print ("\n")
                print  ("Huuuuray! Winner is ", player2)
                print ("Press any key to exit")
                break
 main()
```

Comment: These shouldn't be methods, and the GameOn class is pointless; remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a class, you must add the self parameter first, like this:

```
class GameOn():

  def RollDice(self):
    ...

  def CheckForLadder(self):
    ...

  def CheckForSnake(self):
    ...


  def main(self):
      while (currentPosition1 == 0 and currentPosition2 == 0):
           for player in nameList:
                self.RollDice()
           print("\n")

      while (currentPosition1 <= 105 or currentPosition2 <= 105):
           for player in nameList:
                self.RollDice()
                self.CheckForLadder()
                self.CheckForSnake()
           print("\n")

           if currentPosition1 >= 100:
                print ("\n")
                print  ("Huuuuray! Winner is ", player1)
                print ("Press any key to exit")#finish this
                break

           if currentPosition2 >= 100:
                print ("\n")
                print  ("Huuuuray! Winner is ", player2)
                print ("Press any key to exit")#finish this
                break

game = GameOn()
game.main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I guess it was a pretty silly question and I knew there was a way to do it, just didn't know how... Thanks again !!

Comment: @greenGremlin Come on! there is nothing to thank about! I have always loved to help. And don't worry, everybody starts from the beginning, is normal not know everything :)